# Can't get default language. CFBundleDevelopmentRegion doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, info.plist

I want to set English as the default language in the application.

I know that iOS uses preferred language order to get the language. So I deleted English from this list to test default language. The current iOS language also is not in the preferred language order list.

I expected that iOS would take value from CFBundleDevelopmentRegion but it doesn't work. I got raw key values from localizable.strings instead.

I have English localizable.strings file:

[image]

CFBundleDevelopmentRegion:

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
```

My developer language is English. I tried to set "en" instead "$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)" but got the same result.

Screen from project menu:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: You mean you want English during the development, when you test your application?

Answer (score 1):

You should not delete any file. Go in Project>Scheme>Edit Scheme and set the language you want to use during your tests in the App Language and App Region popups.

[image]

Comment: I test app on a real device.

Comment: Scheme is working the same way for simulator and real device.